# Search an element for a specific string

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Web Page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUcHd.png)
I wanting for it to search each entry summary for a specific string in this case HTTP MethodsIn this tutorial. However, the if statement is not finding the specific string, and I know that it is...
I have tried if substring in articles:, if substring in article:, if substring in header:, if substring in headers:.

Thanks
[Not Finding specific string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6AN4.png)

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")

# searching for element q enters test and hits enter
search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# waits 10 secs until element main appears then searches for 
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
  )

articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")

for article in articles:
    header = article.find_elements_by_class_name("entry-summary")
    print(header.text)



substring = "HTTP MethodsIn this tutorial"
  if substring in header:
    print("Found!")
  else:
    print("Try Again") 

    


finally:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual code you have tried?

Comment: Yes I just updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin.U Which line? What error do you see? Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: header=article.find_elements, will return an array of webelements.  You need to iterate through and get .text or attribute innerHTML and search against that.  You can also just use an xpath to find the text you are looking for.  Use find_elements and if the array returned has zero elements, you know it didn't find it.

Comment: Is your if just not in the for loop?

Comment: Its not an error its just not finding the contains for the if statement. I think it is because I need to Locating Elements by CSS Selectors. But the element doesn't have a variable.

Comment: @DMart Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")

for article in articles:
    header = article.find_elements_by_class_name("entry-summary")
    print(header.text)



    substring = "HTTP MethodsIn this tutorial"
    if substring in header.text:
        print("Found!")
    else:
        print("Try Again")
```

This would print FOUND when it's found. The loop would continue though, not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Thats what I originally thought but it does not.

Comment: oops, forgot to check against header.text